# IIS getting 403 error when it was working before

Tags: windows, iis, permissions, http-status-code-403

There is a virtual machine COQTXX01 with Windows Server 2016 Standard operating system. It has IIS 10.0.

We had an employee Joe who recently left the job. Joe's user account still exist on domain. On this machine there is a **C:\company_sites** folder. Joe created that folder so he is owner of that folder.

Another employee Paul created a new site QTA8888 in **C:\company_sites\QTA8888** folder. Paul created that folder so he is owner of that folder. The Site uses ApplicationPoolIdentity and is bind to a URL. On **C:\company_sites\QTA8888** folder, the COQTXX01\IIS_IUSRS group has full control.

Now when I try to access QTA8888 via URL, I get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied error message.

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
> credentials that you supplied.

What could be the reason? I am a bit new to IIS stuff.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Learn the substatus code first.

Comment: @LexLi 14 is the substatus code

Comment: Then very likely you used a wrong URL that's not for the web app (quite typical an issue to access MVC based web apps). Ask Paul what's the expected URL to use and let him show you the right way to go.

Comment: @ChumboChappati Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you installed iis .net feature.

add below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

and make sure this is set if you are restricted users in your config file:

```
<allow  users="?" />
```